# Golang - how Struct in internal be implemented?

Tags: go

I'm quite confusing about the struct in Go.

This is the code: http://play.golang.org/p/b1NEh7JZoK

Why I could't get the address of a variable to a struct?

If I have two int variables, one stores value, one stores address(pointer), like this : http://play.golang.org/p/XhvKX-ifdn

I can get the actual address of these two variables, but why struct can't?

Comment: Regarding "entire value copied" in your comment to the answer: Yes, using a `non-pointer method-receiver` gets the struct copied. Using a `pointer method-receiver` the original struct will be operated on. Saw [a blog about this](http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/08/09/dont-get-bitten-by-pointer-vs-non-pointer-method-receivers-in-golang/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fmt.Println` prints things in a more readable format. If you want to actually see the addresses, use `fmt.Printf` with `%p` verb:

```
fmt.Printf("%p\n", &a)          // 0x10328000
fmt.Printf("%p -> %p\n", &b, b) // 0x1030e0c0 -> 0x10328000
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/rzZSwIF7UR).

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I found a interesting thing, this is my code : http://play.golang.org/p/J20Rwvzxxs

Comment: if a struct implements an interface, when we assign a pointer to an instance of this struct to an interface variable, and call the method on it, in function it actually gets the entire value copied from the value this pointer pointed to.

Comment: If my understanding right, or there is something wrong?

Comment: I didn't get your question. Please read [Resources for new Go programmers](http://dave.cheney.net/resources-for-new-go-programmers) (especially the [tour](http://tour.golang.org)) and [this article on interfaces in Go](http://research.swtch.com/interfaces).